# Alter a footer during the booking funnel?

Tags: booking, travel

We have a redesigned footer for a travel website that is ready to go live but there has been talk about creating a leaner version when a user is in the booking funnel (summary page, add extras and checkout).

Has anyone experienced this before? My argument is to keep it the same to maintain consistency across the entire website. But stakeholders want less to reduce distractions.

What are peoples thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing the distractions to a minimum raises the chance that your users will actually book something on your site.

Its pretty common that websites change the header to a minimalistic header that removes part of the navigation and/or just displays the logo.

Therefor i think reducing the footer to a minimum can make sense when we talk about something like the booking-funnel.

Of course, booking relevant topics should still be displayed in the footer (for example stuff like "guarantee", "trusted shop" and stuff like that).

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply! Onwards with my stripped down design.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed a mini-footer or no footer at all in the checkout funnel and I personally think it makes a lot of sense as the checkout step is actually from which the company will make money so you want this step to be as clear as possible and with minimum amount of distractions.

Booking funnel? I usually book with 1 click.. If you have more complex system and it is crucial then I would definitely re-define what is important to leave on the page and what is not. E.g. Links to blog or press sections etc